# How can I deploy Elasticsearch on Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, deployment, service, yaml

How can I deploy Elasticsearch on Kubernetes cluster? I need to use the Elasticsearch outside to my cluster. For that, which service that I should use? Can anyone post the deployment and service yaml files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the helm chart to deploy the elasticsearch if you want to run it in production.

Helm chart : https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts

If you are just deploying for development and testing you can below YAML file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app : elasticsearch
    component: elasticsearch
    release: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app : elasticsearch
      component: elasticsearch
      release: elasticsearch
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app : elasticsearch
        component: elasticsearch
        release: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: cluster.name
          value: <SET THIS>
        - name: discovery.type
          value: single-node
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
        - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
          value: "false"
        image: elasticsearch:6.5.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: elasticsearch
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 150m
            memory: 512Mi
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: elasticsearch-data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
        - chmod 777 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - chomod 777 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/node
        - chmod g+rwx /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - chgrp 1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        image: busybox:1.29.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: set-dir-owner
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: elasticsearch-data
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: elasticsearch-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

Ref Gist : https://gist.github.com/harsh4870/ccd6ef71eaac2f09d7e136307e3ecda6

> which service that I should use

You can expose the Elasticsearch service with type **LoadBalancer** and expose it to internet and use it.

**service.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eks-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
    component: elasticsearch
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
    - name: monitoring
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9300
      targetPort: 9300
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**Note :**

you need to use the **NodePort** or **LoadBalancer** as service type with **ClusterIp** you wont be able to expose service unless you use some **proxy** setup or **ingress**.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, you can use helm charts, however Elastic has also published its [own operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-quickstart.html) which is a significantly more robust option than deploying a bare statefulSet

To install the operator:

```
kubectl create -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/2.0.0/crds.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/2.0.0/operator.yaml
```

And to deploy a cluster

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 8.0.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
EOF
```

If you want to have this production ready, you probably want to make some further adjustments that you can all find in [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-customize-pods.html)

Answer (score 1):

well, the following yamls works for me
elasticsearch-deploy.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  replicas: 1 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: elasticsearch:7.9.0
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 4Gi
          limits:
            memory: 5Gi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
        - containerPort: 9300
        env:
        - name: discovery.type
          value: single-node
```

Now, we wants to access this elastic-search from outside our cluster.By default deployments will assign clusterip service which is used to access the pods inside the same cluster.Here we use NodePort service to access outside our cluster.
elasticsearch-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: esservice
spec:
  selector: 
    app: elasticsearch
  type: NodePort  
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
      nodePort: 31200
```

this makes your service to access from your browser by:

```
HTTP://<nodeip>:<nodeport>
```

eg: `HTTP://192.168.18.90:31200/`
output be like:

```
name    "elasticsearch-5974b56749-fj8n7"
cluster_name    "docker-cluster"
cluster_uuid    "4o-NidnuSSiBI-RwEPWEVQ"
version 
number  "7.9.0"
build_flavor    "default"
build_type  "docker"
build_hash  "a479a2a7fce0389512d6a9361301708b92dff667"
build_date  "2020-08-11T21:36:48.204330Z"
build_snapshot  false
lucene_version  "8.6.0"
minimum_wire_compatibility_version  "6.8.0"
minimum_index_compatibility_version "6.0.0-beta1"
tagline "You Know, for Search"
```

Comment: looks like it;s without the PVC data will be lost if the container goes down or so and update on this ? you can update the status of question.

Comment: Why did you define two different ports? 9200 and 9300

Answer (score 0):

You can try using YAML file as belwo:

```
kind: StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    com/es: es
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
          com/es: es
  template:
     metadata:
      labels:
        com/es: es
    spec:
      containers:
        - resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          name: elasticsearch
          env:
            - name: discovery.type
              value: single-node
          ports:
            - name: rest
              containerPort: 9200
              protocol: TCP
            - name: inter-node
              containerPort: 9300
              protocol: TCP
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - name: <volume-name>
              mountPath: <mount-path>
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2'
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: <image-pullsecret>
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: es-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 15Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
  serviceName: es-service
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
```

> You can use this yaml which creates statefulset, statefullset will
> internally create the elaticsearch pod. If you want volume mount you
> can add your volume mount data which is mentioned in this yaml. if you
> don't delete the volume section from the spec and
> volumeClaimTemplates.

To use the elasticsearch out-side to cluster, try this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: es-service
  labels:
    com/es: es
spec:
  ports:
    - name: rest
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
    - name: inter-node
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9300
      targetPort: 9300
  selector:
    com/es: es
  clusterIP: <ip of your cluster>
  clusterIPs:
    -  <ip of your cluster>
  type: ClusterIP

  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
```

Answer (score 0):

this manifest (deployment.yaml) works for me in GCP Kubernetes Engine,
you run the with the command:

> kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  replicas: 1 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: elasticsearch:7.9.0
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 2Gi
          limits:
            memory: 4Gi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
        - containerPort: 9300
        env:
        - name: discovery.type
          value: single-node
```

and with this service you can check with a external IP (http://serviceIP:9200), run the same:

> kubectl apply -f service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: esservice
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9200
    targetPort: 9200
```

Comment: I have 3 clusters on Kubernetes, in this case, will it be a problem if I use discovery.type: single-node?

Comment: sorry, i've not experimented with multiple cluster, i've only seen that they use replicas https://blog.knoldus.com/how-to-set-up-a-2-node-elasticsearch-cluster-on-kubernetes-minikube/